# Are AWS EC2 instances docker images or virtual machines?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

If I am not wrong Amazon Web Services (AWS) uses Docker containerization.

Does EC2 service uses Docker technology or it is another different one such as real virtual machines or others?

Comment: Why the downvote?At least explain why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EC2 instances are set up using [Amazon Machine Images (AMI)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html), Amazon proprietary not based on Docker.

> Linux Amazon Machine Images use one of two types of virtualization: paravirtual (PV) or hardware virtual machine (HVM). The main differences between PV and HVM AMIs are the way in which they boot and whether they can take advantage of special hardware extensions (CPU, network, and storage) for better performance.

Comment: They're proprietary in a sense, but not entirely so.  AMIs are just metadata containers for the information needed for bootstrapping instances.  The hypervisors are Xen for most instance types except for some of the newest, which are [based on technology from KVM](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#compute-optimized).

Comment: the difference between PV and HMVM as you reported seems the same to the one between a virtual machine and a Docker container.

Answer (score 0):

EC2 is a virtual machine and you can have full root access control with it as for registered users of AWS